# SharePoint 2013: Get multiple UserProfile with REST API

Tags: web-part, user-profile, sharepoint-rest-api

There are over 10000 User Profiles.

So I want to get all user Profiles in single request with all user properties.

Is it possible to get multiple users in single request matching particular criteria?

I need to know what will be the best approach from the performance point of view? It can't afford to be slower.

Please suggest something.

Answer (score 2):

There is no API to get all user profile in a single request. You need some filter and paging to get user profiles.

## Using Search API

```
{site url}/_api/search/query?querytext='FirstName=A*'&startrow=0&rowlimit=100&sourceid='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31'
```

In first request, above API will return you 100 profiles who have first name started with `A`. In second request `startrow` will be `100`. This way you can get your all user profiles.

## Using UserInformationList

You can get all user profiles under your current logged in site from below end-point. Make a GET request to the following **URL**.

```
/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList?$skip=0&$top=100
```

In next requests increment the value of `$skip` `(previous + 100)`.

Comment: User Information list may not contain **all** users, I would say it's dangerous to rely on the user list.

Comment: I also said that it does not contain. It contains all profiles of current site users.

Comment: Should be 'FirstName:A*' instead of 'FirstName=A*' I think?